# Umbraco dictionary translations are not working correctly on localhost

Tags: dictionary, umbraco, translation, umbraco6

I have downloaded an Umbraco 6 site and I have tried replicating the environment locally in my machine, using the production database and the compiled site from production.

If I go to the Umbraco backoffce and to the `Settings` => `Dictionary` entries, I can see a specific dictionary entry in multiple languages.

This entry is displayed correctly in production when the user chooses a different language. However, locally, when I change the language, the dictionary item still appears in english (the default language and does not get translated).

I have tried running the site through Visual Studio and WebMatrix, to check if this was some issue with the webserver settings locally, as this might be session related, but the issue still happens.

Is there a reason why translation for dictionary items is not working as expected? Content that is created through nodes and translated there is showing up in the correct language, but dictionary items are not.

**UPDATE**

I am now looking into something that could be responsible for this. When I am at the content area and select one of the language nodes and head to properties, I see multiple "Alternative links", which contain URLs to the same page on different domains. I don't see `localhost:XXXX/EN.aspx` there, which makes me wonder as to whether or not the site is handling the language detection correctly in `localhost`. I haven't found how to add additional links there, and be able to use a wildcard for port would be interesting.

Comment: Right click on the node - "Manage hostnames" and add localhost domain and language you want.

Comment: @DavorZlotrg your suggestion helped resolve at least part of the issue. I have added another hostname, but instead of localhost I created a new hostname for the site. However, the language selection dropdown points URLs to the production environment and not the one I just added. Is there any additional step I need to do? By the way, please provide your comment as an answer so I can mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should right click on the node - select "Culture and Hostnames" and add your domain there.

After that right click on the root "Content" node and click on "Republish entire site" - that should clear the cache and you should be able to see the new url under "Alternative links".

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Any hint on the additional problem I left on the question comment regarding URLs generated in the language selection dropdown?

Comment: @BlunT I am not sure what you mean by "URLs generated in the language selection dropdown" - could you make a screenshot maybe?